# Connecting LCD monitor (without tv-tuner) to cable-tv

Tags: lcd, tv, hdtv

I have LG W2261 screen (without tv-tuner).
This has HDMI input.
I was wondering if I can buy set-top-box and watch TV on it and have hdtv.
I have tv cable signal with dvb-t connector.
I would like to buy set-top-box (digital receiver) which would convert dvb-t to hdmi signal and connect this to my monitor.

Is it possible?
Thx.

**===============**

It works perfectly. I've just bought cheap (80 euros) tv-setup-box with HDMI output, full HD, USB etc.
I didn't had any problems doing that.

Comment: You should probably mention what country you're in, as different countries use different standards for broadcast and cable TV.

Comment: This is for Denmark TDC Cable. 
I would probably buy things in Germany.
In .dk shop they told me that it is not possible to do that due to fact that "some" frequencies are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-an-LCD-Monitor-as-a-TV-without-a-Computer/) exactly answers the question.
Strange because in a shop they told me that it is not possible because of difference in frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

How about the **[Acer Aspire Revo](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883103228)**...

[image]

and a USB DVB-T dongle?

[image]

costs: around $230

Comment: can i just buy set-top-box (digital receiver) without whole computer?
I have dvb-t signal and I would need to convert it somehow to hdmi first.

Comment: @user20196 - despite being a "whole computer" this thing is much smaller than your average set-top box and it can also serve as a fully fledged HTPC thanks to its nVidia Ion graphics, 1080p is no problem.

Comment: Hi, thx for the answere. I life in Europe and this thing unfortunatelly costs around 300 Euros and set-top-box with hdmi around 50. The difference is too big for me.

Comment: I am looking for cheaper barebones and it looks promising. Thx for the solution.

Comment: @user20196 - mind you, there are two models, look for the one with the N230 CPU, should be cheaper than 300 euro. the N330 dual core Atom Revo is dearer.

Comment: Atom CPU will not handle the 1080p full hd decoding :( it has to be at least intel core duo 2.0Ghz.

Comment: @user20196 - certainly not, even the WD TV Live with its 500 MHz will playback 1080p HD video smoothly, no problem. and here's a video showing the Revo in "1080p action": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3aw1FSqfAU

Comment: @Molly strange because I had a look on elegato EyeTv USB sticks and they say that for 1080p you need Intel Core duo. The movie is great.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few cheap settop boxes that will upscale to 1080i/p, but most come integrated with DVRs or DVD players so you'll be paying more for the extra features.

You don't say where in Europe you are, but most boxes are interchangeable between countries as long as the markets use overlapping frequency ranges. The [SAMSUNG DTB-B460F](http://www.rueducommerce.fr/TV-Hifi-Home-Cinema/TNT-Television-Numerique-Terrestre/Adaptateur-TNT-Enregistreur-numerique/SAMSUNG/5182-Adaptateur-Television-Numerique-Terrestre-DTB-B460F.htm)  (link is to a French site that sells it) is a good example at EUR 125. I've never seen it in action but I've heard it works pretty well.

One thing to be aware of is that you won't be getting the full HD signal from a DVB-T source. You will be getting an upscaled standard definition picture.